# GruntJS recursive globbing difference

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, glob

What's the difference between `**/*.js` and `{,*/}*.js` in GruntJS node globbing?

Answer (score 1):

**GruntJS** uses [globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#globbing-patterns) based [**node-glob**](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) library.

Based on this, `*` will have next meanings:

- `path/*` - all files and folders in `path` **not** recoursive
- `path/**` - everything in `path` recursively
- `path/*.*` - all files and folders with point in name; matches `file.txt`, `.gitignore`, `noExtension.`, etc.

To put some light, you may read this article on [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

In the documentation they have [Glob Primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer), which has an example:

> Before parsing the path part patterns, braced sections are expanded into a set. Braced sections start with `{` and end with `}`, with any number of comma-delimited sections within. Braced sections may contain slash characters, so `a{/b/c,bcd}` would expand into `a/b/c` and `abcd`.

this is exactly what your case `{,*/}*.js` is about.

I'd highly recommend to use syntax `**` (in your case it's `**/*.js`, for filtering `.js` files only) when you need to iterate path **recursively**.